# CDATA Parsing Values

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am parsing CDATA but i am gettings the values...
`http://nikelebron.net/feed/` and `http://www.nicekicks.com/feed/` in this both rss feeds i want get **src** value in tag

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
 NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock  
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my question detector needs adjustment, but I can't tell what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will print all the **jpg image links** in the CDATA,

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock{
    NSString *cDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDataDetector *detect = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [detect matchesInString:cDataString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [cDataString length])];

    for(int i=0; i<matches.count;i++){
      NSTextCheckingResult *result = [matches objectAtIndex:i];
      NSString *linkUrl = [result URL].absoluteString;


      if([[linkUrl pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]){
      //for your requirement, change the above line to
      //NSString *pathExtension = [linkUrl pathExtension];
      //if((pathExtension.length>=3)&&([[pathExtension substringToIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"jpg"])){
       NSLog(@"image link:%@", linkUrl);
      }else NSLog(@"link:%@", linkUrl);

    }
}
```

Comment: its not working for this link "http://www.nicekicks.com/feed/"

Comment: Ok, for that change the image link detection line to this, if([[[linkUrl pathExtension] substringToIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"jpg"]){

Comment: @bati, I added few comments in the code. Please check it

Comment: i got the following error

Comment: [__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: NSString *pathExtension = [linkUrl pathExtension];
if((pathExtension.length>=3)&&([[pathExtension substringToIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"jpg"])){